# Azure Logic App set priority when creating Jira issue

Tags: automation, set, connection, jira, azure-logic-apps

So I am working on a project to create Jira issue automatically from Logic App.

I want to ask if there is a way to set the priority also.

For creating the ticket this is the only fields that can set.

[image: View the attach img]

Answer (score 0):

To make it visible over Logic Apps, you need to check the required box in the field but currently Logic Apps do not support jira field types other than string, number, date and datetime.

[image]

[image]

However as an alterative, You can add a short text field to enter the priority level.

***In jira***

[image]

***In LogicApps***

[image]

For more information, You can refer [Jira Connector - Known Issues and Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/jira/#known-issues-and-limitations)